# Reduce a MeijerG to elementary function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

The following function for $t>0$

```
f[t_]:=1/(8 (-1+E^(2 t)) \[Pi]^(3/2)) E^t (MeijerG[{{1/2,1,3/2},{}},{{3/2},{}},-((2 I)/(5 t)),1/2]+MeijerG[{{1/2,1,3/2},{}},{{3/2},{}},(2 I)/(5 t),1/2]-MeijerG[{{1/2,1,3/2},{}},{{3/2},{}},-((2 I)/(3 t)),1/2]-MeijerG[{{1/2,1,3/2},{}},{{3/2},{}},(2 I)/(3 t),1/2])
```

is actually an elementary function, by

```
Plot[Evaluate[4Exp[4t]f[t]],{t,0,1},WorkingPrecision->20]
```

[image]

but `FunctionExpand` can not simplify it,

```
FunctionExpand[f[t],Assumptions->t>0]
```

[image]

Mathematica will automatically abort the evaluation. Using

```
AbortProtect@Trace@FunctionExpand[f[t],Assumptions->t>0]
```

we can trace the intermediate steps, but I didn't get some useful information from that.

Is there some other way to deal with MeijerG functions (if not for Mathematica, is there some useful Python package for this?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Mathematica is not trying any of the known transformations of the Meijer G-functions.

We can use the second formula on [this Wolfram Functions page](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG1/16/01/01/),

```
f[t_] = 1/(8 (-1 + E^(2 t)) π^(3/2)) E^t (
  MeijerG[{{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {}}, {{3/2}, {}}, -((2 I)/(5 t)), 1/2] +
  MeijerG[{{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {}}, {{3/2}, {}}, (2 I)/(5 t), 1/2] - 
  MeijerG[{{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {}}, {{3/2}, {}}, -((2 I)/(3 t)), 1/2] - 
  MeijerG[{{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {}}, {{3/2}, {}}, (2 I)/(3 t), 1/2]);

f[t] /. MeijerG[a_, b_, z_, r_] :> MeijerG[1 - b, 1 - a, 1/z, r] //
  FullSimplify[#, t > 0] &

(*    E^(-4 t)/4    *)
```

Comment: Note that `Entity["MathematicalFunction", "MeijerG"]["Dataset"]` contains no entries, not even a link to the Wolfram Functions Site.

Comment: @BobHanlon A bug? Can you populate it? Strange, there is even Meijer GRepresentation row.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников - only Wolfram can populate their database.